# The rightCalloutAccessory button is not shown

Tags: ios5, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I try to manage annotations, and to display an info button on the right of the view when a PIN get selected, my relevant code is this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"greenPin"];

        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[ManageAnnotations class]]) {
            static NSString* identifier = @"ManageAnnotations";   

            MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            if (newAnnotation==nil) {
                newAnnotation=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            }else {
                newAnnotation.annotation=annotation;
            }

            newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
            newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
            newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
            newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

            return newAnnotation;


        }else {
            newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
            newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
            newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
            return newAnnotation;
        }
```

**ManageAnnotations.m :**

```
@implementation ManageAnnotations

@synthesize pinColor;
@synthesize storeName=_storeName;
@synthesize storeAdress=_storeAdress;
@synthesize coordinate=_coordinate;


-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)storeName adress:(NSString*)storeAdress coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

    if((self=[super init])){
        _storeName=[storeName copy];
        _storeAdress=[storeAdress copy];
        _coordinate=coordinate;

    }
    return self;

}
-(NSString*)title{

    return _storeName;
}
-(NSString*)subtitle{

    return _storeAdress;


}
```

**ManageAnnotations.h**

```
@interface ManageAnnotations : NSObject<MKAnnotation>{

    NSString *_storeName;
    NSString *_storeAdress;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;

}
//
@property(nonatomic,assign)MKPinAnnotationColor pinColor;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy)NSString *storeName;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy)NSString *storeAdress;
@property(nonatomic,readonly)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;



//
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)storeName adress:(NSString*)storeAdress coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
//
```

The PINS are shown correctly on the Map, but without the info button on the right of the view. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are you actually going into the condition? Set a breakpoint to check.
2. Why create a MKPinAnnotationView at the beginning, before you know the type of annotation?
3. You should dequeue your annotationView instead of alloc/initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier
4. When you reuse your annotations, you should put everything that doesn't change (color, animation, etc) after the alloc init, and not reset them all the time. Otherwise you lose the interest of reusing.

Other than that your code seems fine, and comparing it to mine, I don't see anything obvious. Remark 1 is the most probable. I would set a breakpoint to see if I really go there, see if I can show a leftCalloutAccessoryView instead, use a different pinColor.

Comment: Actually, yes, i don't get there, i chef it with a breakpoint. What probably seems to be the problem of not calling that `viewForAnnotation` method please ?

Comment: Oh, i have forgotten to set the delegate :/  Thanx for your help, problem solved :)))